# Why is the proof counter for Prime number is not working

Tags: java, primes

I was trying to make a program detecting prime factor. Here's the flow:

1. Detecting if a number is factor
2. If it is the factor / f, divide it sequentially starting from f-1, f-2,...
3. For any division with remainder, the proof counter will increment
4. If the final proof counter = f-2, it will inform PRIME FACTOR

However, when the program is run, the "for loop" of proof counter part won't work.

For example, when the factor is 6, the proof will only works for:

- 6 % 5
- 6 % 4
- Proof counter = 2

[image: tried to print screen the output here]

and then jumped to look for another  factor

I wonder why is this happening?

(Am sorry if this question is messy)

int N = input.nextInt();

```
    for(int i =N; i>1; i--){
        if(N%i == 0){
            f = i;
            int proof = 0;

            System.out.println("factor:" + f);

            for(int j = f-1; j>=1; j--){
                if(f%j != 0){
                    proof++;
                    System.out.println("proved when j is " + j);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("no of proof"+proof);
            if(proof == f-2){
                    System.out.println(f + "is PRIME");


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Break out of the loop if the condition `proof == f - 2` is met.

Comment: @DrewReese the proof counter is going wrong, so there's not much chance of meeting the condition lol

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mcve] which includes the declarations of `f`, `proof` etc. Additionally please also provide examples of where it didn't work, what you expected and what you got in those cases.

Comment: What /where is the initial value of `proof`? Where is it reset for each iteration?

Comment: @Thomas Hi I tried to include the output screen  shot

Comment: @DrewReese sorry that line of codes dissapeared when paste it here lol lemme put it back

Comment: What is the result? You just want to retrieve `true/false` for `prime/not prime` numbers?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik I wanted to detect the prime factor, and it happened when proof counter == factor -2

Comment: Your algorithm only displays "proofs" when they do not divide the factor. 3 & 2 both divide 6 so nothing is printed.

Answer (score -1):

3 & 2 both divide 6, so nothing is outputted in your code. If you want to see the algorithm try those numbers then you need to also print out all the attempts in addition to the ones you proved.

```
int N = input.nextInt();

for (int i = N; i > 1; i--) {
  if (N % i == 0) {
    int f = i;
    int proof = 0;

    System.out.println("factor:" + f);

    for (int j = f - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
      System.out.println("j: " + j); // <-- current value proving
      if (f % j != 0) {
        proof++;
        System.out.println("proved when j is " + j);
      }
    }
    System.out.println("no of proof" + proof);
    if (proof == f - 2) {
      System.out.println(f + "is PRIME");
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a running javascript version of your algorithm that displays the continued calculations.

```js
let N = 6;

for(let i = N; i > 1; i--) {
  console.log(`${N} % ${i}`);
  if (N % i === 0) {
    let f = i;
    let proof = 0;

    console.log("factor:", f);

    for(let j = f - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
      console.log('j', j); // show attempts here
      if (f % j !== 0) {
        proof++;
        console.log("proved when j is " + j);
      }
    }
    
    if (proof === f-2) {
      console.log(f + " is PRIME");
    }
    console.log("number of proofs: " + proof);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you switch languages?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have an executable platform for Java afaik and this issue seems more related to algorithm than language. That is why I prefaced it with "This is a javascript version..."